How to refer to a Json file instead
Here is my HTML script that uses JavaScript and a schedule format to set a timer for the part of the day. Can someone help me get this to work with linking the Schedule to a JSON file so it can be swapped out easier?
How do I make this code so when it needs the schedule it refers to a txt file called "Schedule.txt" instead:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Class Timer</title>
<style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Class Timer</h1>
<p id="class-info"></p>
<p id="countdown"></p>

<script>
    // Schedule data, can be easily updated!
    const schedule = {
        "Monday": [
            { "class": "1/5", "start": "08:30", "end": "09:54" },
            { "class": "2/6", "start": "10:00", "end": "11:24" },
            { "class": "Advisory", "start": "11:30", "end": "12:00" },
            { "class": "Lunch A", "start": "12:00", "end": "12:30" },
            { "class": "3A/7A", "start": "12:36", "end": "14:00" },
            { "class": "3B/7B", "start": "12:06", "end": "13:30" },
            { "class": "Lunch B", "start": "13:30", "end": "14:00" },
            { "class": "4/8", "start": "14:06", "end": "15:30" }
        ],
        "Tuesday": [
            { "class": "1/5", "start": "08:30", "end": "10:03" },
            { "class": "2/6", "start": "10:09", "end": "11:42" },
            { "class": "Lunch A", "start": "11:42", "end": "12:12" },
            { "class": "3A/7A", "start": "12:18", "end": "13:51" },
            { "class": "3B/7B", "start": "11:48", "end": "13:21" },
            { "class": "Lunch B", "start": "13:21", "end": "13:51" },
            { "class": "4/8", "start": "13:57", "end": "15:30" }
        ],
        "Wednesday": [
            { "class": "1/5", "start": "09:00", "end": "10:26" },
            { "class": "2/6", "start": "10:31", "end": "11:58" },
            { "class": "Lunch A", "start": "11:58", "end": "12:28" },
            { "class": "3A/7A", "start": "12:34", "end": "13:59" },
            { "class": "3B/7B", "start": "12:04", "end": "13:29" },
            { "class": "Lunch B", "start": "13:29", "end": "13:59" },
            { "class": "4/8", "start": "14:05", "end": "15:30" }
        ],
        "Thursday": [
            { "class": "1/5", "start": "08:30", "end": "09:49" },
            { "class": "2/6", "start": "09:55", "end": "11:19" },
            { "class": "Advisory", "start": "11:25", "end": "12:10" },
            { "class": "Lunch A", "start": "12:10", "end": "12:40" },
            { "class": "3A/7A", "start": "12:46", "end": "14:06" },
            { "class": "3B/7B", "start": "12:16", "end": "13:36" },
            { "class": "Lunch B", "start": "13:36", "end": "14:06" },
            { "class": "4/8", "start": "14:12", "end": "15:30" }
        ],
        "Friday": [
            { "class": "1/5", "start": "08:30", "end": "09:49" },
            { "class": "2/6", "start": "09:55", "end": "11:19" },
            { "class": "Advisory", "start": "11:25", "end": "12:10" },
            { "class": "Lunch A", "start": "12:10", "end": "12:40" },
            { "class": "3A/7A", "start": "12:46", "end": "14:06" },
            { "class": "3B/7B", "start": "12:16", "end": "13:36" },
            { "class": "Lunch B", "start": "13:36", "end": "14:06" },
            { "class": "4/8", "start": "14:12", "end": "15:30" }
        ]
    };

    // The thing to calculate the time until the next class
    function calculateNextClass() {
        const now = new Date();
        const dayOfWeek = now.toLocaleString('en-US', { weekday: 'long' });
        const currentTime = now.getHours() * 60 + now.getMinutes();

        const classesToday = schedule[dayOfWeek];
        for (let i = 0; i < classesToday.length; i++) {
            const classStart = convertToMinutes(classesToday[i].start);
            if (classStart > currentTime) {
                const timeUntilNextClass = classStart - currentTime;
                return { class: classesToday[i].class, time: timeUntilNextClass };
            }
        }
        return { class: "No classes left for today", time: 0 };
    }

    // Function to convert time in Hours and minutes format to minutes since midnight
    function convertToMinutes(timeString) {
        const [hours, minutes] = timeString.split(":").map(Number);
        return hours * 60 + minutes;
    }

    // Function to update the timer display
    function updateTimer() {
        const nextClass = calculateNextClass();
        const hours = Math.floor(nextClass.time / 60);
        const minutes = nextClass.time % 60;
        const seconds = 60 - new Date().getSeconds(); 

        document.getElementById("class-info").textContent = `Next Class: ${nextClass.class}`;
        document.getElementById("countdown").textContent = `Time until next class: ${hours}h ${minutes}m ${seconds}s`;
    }

    // Timer Display
    setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>


I tried using ChatGPT to help figure out the problem but every time I tried what it said it broke the code.

You need Node.js if you're trying to read a local file automatically, otherwise you'd have to give it a remote URL to a document that it can retrieve with fetch AFAIK

What part of getting it from a file is giving you a problem? Just use fetch() to fetch the file from the server, parse it as JSON, and the rest of the code is the same.

@AaronMeese It doesn't have to be node.js. It can be a static JSON file that they fetch from the server.

@Barmar that's what I said. To read a local file you need Node, to get a file from a server you can use fetch

@AaronMeese But you can't run Node code in the browser. If you run it on your local PC, it's acting as a server.

const schedule = await (await fetch('./data.json')).json();

As the other comments suggested and probably the best approach would be to have your JSON on a server and fetch it from there like this:
fetch('./data.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json));

You can either have your own server, like Node, which deals with your fetch requests, or an easier solution might be to host your JSON online and send the fetch request to that service (https://www.jsonkeeper.com/, https://jsonbin.io/)
This article documents some methods that might interest you:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-read-json-file-in-javascript/
